# Criação tabela com filtro dinamico

Tags: php, ajax

O meu intuito é criar filtros para aparecerem as colunas todas inicialmente e poder escolher as colunas que aparecem através de checkbox.
Alguém me consegue ajudar a fazer isso?

```
 <div class= "form-group"
     <input type="checkbox" class= "btn btn-default" id="Utilizador" value = "Utilizador">Utilizador
     <input type="checkbox" class= "btn btn-default" id="Ano" value="Ano">Ano
 </div>
<br>



    

<?php
         include('conetar.php');


         //------Lançamento de tabela-------//
       
      
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT equipamentos.IDEquipamento, equipamentos.Modelo, equipamentos.Ano, equipamentos.Estado, utilizadores.Nome, utilizadores.IDUtilizador FROM `equipamentos` left join utilizadores on equipamentos.IDUtilizador = utilizadores.IDUtilizador");
       

                    echo "<table width='100% class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'id='datatables-example'>
                        <tr>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td class='pure-table'><b>ID</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Modelo</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Ano</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Utilizador</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Estado</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Editar</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Histórico</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Apagar</b></td>
                        </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {

                    echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['IDEquipamento'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Modelo'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Ano'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Nome'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Estado'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='formsEquipmentsUpdate.php?IDEquipamento=".$row['IDEquipamento']."&IDUtilizador=".$row['IDUtilizador']."'>Update</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='tablesHistoryMachine.php?IDEquipamento=".$row['IDEquipamento']. "&IDUtilizador=".$row['IDUtilizador']."'>Histórico</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='deleteEquipment.php?IDEquipamento=".$row['IDEquipamento']."'>Delete</a></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</tbody>";    
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

[image]

Quero que na tabela apenas apareça a coluna Utilizadores ou a coluna Ano ou entao as duas.

Answer (score 2):

Algumas dúvidas:

1)deve atualizar ao clicar no checkbox?

2)deve fazer consulta asíncrona ao clicar no checkbox?(usando ajax)

**CASO QUEIRA ALGO VIA AJAX:**

1) use Jquery para ao clicar no checkbox ele enviar ajax:

```
$(function(){
    $("#Utilizador,#Ano").click(function() {
       $.ajax({
          url: "ajax_atualiza_tabela.php",
          type: "GET",
          data:'utilizador='+$('#Utilizador').val()+'&ano='+$("#Ano").val(),
          beforeSend: function(){
          },
          complete: function(){
          },
          success: function(result){
          $("#tabela").html(result);
       }
    });
});
```

});

**ajax_atualiza_tabela.php:**

```
<?php
         include('conetar.php');
         /* VERIFICANDO CHECKBOXES */
         $colunaUtilizador = $_GET['utilizador'];
         $colunaAno = $_GET['ano'];

         $sql = "SELECT equipamentos.IDEquipamento, equipamentos.Modelo, equipamentos.Estado, utilizadores.IDUtilizador";

         if($colunaUtilizador) {
            $sql .= ',utilizadores.Nome';
         }
         if($colunaAno) {
            $sql .= ',equipamentos.Ano';
         }
         $sql .= ' FROM `equipamentos` left join utilizadores on equipamentos.IDUtilizador = utilizadores.IDUtilizador';




         //------Lançamento de tabela-------//


        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


                    echo "<table width='100% class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'id='datatables-example'>
                        <tr>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td class='pure-table'><b>ID</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Modelo</b></td>";
                            if($colunaAno)                                
                               echo "<td class='pure-table'><b>Ano</b></td>";
                            if($colunaUtilizador)
                               echo "<td class='pure-table'><b>Utilizador</b></td>";

                            echo "<td class='pure-table'><b>Estado</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Editar</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Histórico</b></td>
                            <td class='pure-table'><b>Apagar</b></td>
                        </tr>";
        echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['IDEquipamento'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Modelo'] . "</td>";
                    if($colunaAno) 
                       echo "<td>" . $row['Ano'] . "</td>";
                    if($colunaUtilizador)                        
                       echo "<td>" . $row['Nome'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Estado'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='formsEquipmentsUpdate.php?IDEquipamento=".$row['IDEquipamento']."&IDUtilizador=".$row['IDUtilizador']."'>Update</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='tablesHistoryMachine.php?IDEquipamento=".$row['IDEquipamento']. "&IDUtilizador=".$row['IDUtilizador']."'>Histórico</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='deleteEquipment.php?IDEquipamento=".$row['IDEquipamento']."'>Delete</a></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>";    
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

**INDEX.HTML:**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT>
       $(function(){
          $("#Utilizador,Ano").click(function() {
          $.ajax({
           url: "ajax_atualiza_tabela.php",
           type: "GET",
           data:'utilizador='+$('#Utilizador').val()+'&ano='+$("#Ano").val(),
           beforeSend: function(){
           },
           complete: function(){
           },
           success: function(result){
              $("#tabela").html(result);
           }
        });
    });
});
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <div class= "form-group">
     <input type="checkbox" class= "btn btn-default" id="Utilizador" value = "Utilizador">Utilizador
     <input type="checkbox" class= "btn btn-default" id="Ano" value="Ano">Ano
   </div>
   <div id="tabela">

   </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

PS. Não esqueca de incluir o jquery no cabeçalho da pagina

Comment: A resposta as suas perguntas é Sim a ambas

Comment: Da forma como fez, não esta a funcionar

Comment: qual erro apresentado?

Comment: fiz umas pequenas modificacoes no codigo, fechamento do while que tava aberto por exemplo

Comment: Apenas não executa o pedido ao clicar numa das `checkbox`

Comment: No codigo `php`, a concatenação da `query` terá de ser assim :

 $sql = "SELECT equipamentos.IDEquipamento, equipamentos.Modelo, equipamentos.Estado, utilizadores.IDUtilizador" ;

         if($colunaUtilizador) {
            $sql .= ',utilizadores.Nome';
         }
         if($colunaAno) {
            $sql .= ',equipamentos.Ano';
         }
         $sql .= ' FROM `equipamentos` left join utilizadores on equipamentos.IDUtilizador = utilizadores.IDUtilizador';

Comment: arrumado, e possível erro de "nada acontecer ao clicar", podia ter sido pelo motivo de que o js era executado antes de carregar o HTML, daí era só forcar ele começar após construir/ desenhar o html, mais sobre https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/